# React data do not appears on the screen

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, http-status-code-403

**what am I doing wrong**

**I'm making a rest request but I'm not getting the data**

**I'm having the 403 error**

**is there any parameter missing**

**I tested the api on insomnia and it's working**

**the data appears on the console but does not appear on the screen**

**Code API below**

**How can I Solve this?**

**I am New With React**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Utils from '../atendimento/utils';
const URL = `${Utils.ngrok_service}/protocol/generate`;

const protocolGet = (clientCode, _success, _error) => {
  if (!!clientCode) {
    const options = {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' },
    };
    const Code = {
      codigoCliente: String(clientCode).split(' ').join(''),
    };

    axios
      .post(URL, Code, options)
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
          if (typeof _success === 'function') _success(data);
        } else {
          if (typeof _error === 'function') {
            _error({
              code: 404,
              message: 'Falha ao gerar um protocolo.',
            });
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (typeof _error === 'function') {
          _error({
            code: 400,
            message: 'Falha ao gerar um protocolo.',
          });
        }
      });
  }
};

export default protocolGet;
```

Code JSX Bellow:

```
class SelectTabs extends Component {

    constructor ( props ) {

        super( props );

        this.state = {
            options: [],
            cusProtocol:"",
            isReady: false
        };

        this.loadTabs = this.loadTabs.bind( this );
        this.makeOptions = this.makeOptions.bind( this );
    }

    componentDidMount ( ) {

        console.log('[SelectTabs] rendered with props: ', this.props );
        this.loadTabs();
    }

    loadTabs ( ) {
        protocolGet( "123245",cusProtocol => {
            console.log('[SelectProtocol] cusProtocol: ', cusProtocol );
            this.setState({ cusProtocol });

        }, error => {

            console.log('[SelectProtocol] Não foi possível consultar o serviço: ');
            console.log( error );
        });

         tabGet( options => {

             console.log('[SelectTabs] options: ', options );
             this.setState({ options });

         }, error => {

             console.log('[SelectTabs] Não foi possível consultar o serviço: ');
             console.log( error );
         });
    }

    makeOptions ( object ) {

        const options = object.map( data => {
            return {
                value: data,
                label: data
            }
        });

        return options;
    }

    render ( ) {

        const $Task = this.props.task;
        const selectProps = {
            isRtl: false,
            isMulti: false,
            isClearable: false,
            isSearchable: false,
            placeholder: 'Selecione',
            noOptionsMessage: () => 'Aguarde...'
        };
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                    <SC.Container>
                    <SC.Title>Protocolo</SC.Title>
                    <SC.Input>
                                <TextareaAutosize disabled type="text" value={
                                    this.state.cusProtocol
                                }/>
                            </SC.Input>

                        <SC.Title>Tabulação</SC.Title>
                        <Select
                            { ...selectProps }
                            options={ this.makeOptions( this.state.options ) }
                            onChange={ event => {} }
                        />
                    </SC.Container>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
```

[image: imagem]

[image: image two]

Comment: anyone can help me please??

Comment: when you do this line? `then((response) => {` can you `console.log(response)` underneath and show what it is

Comment: I Dont know, the cusProtocol don't appear on the screen

Comment: well you need to help me out by telling me what is in the data otherwise I wont have a chance in helping you im afraid

Comment: I put an console image in the question, I don't know How it is Help you

Comment: there are two images